# How can I change progressDialog to ProgressBar?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've returned to old project of mine and slowly fixing things to make it work again. It was [Android 9.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Pie) (Pie)-[Android 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_10) when I first started and now I changed it to [Android 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_13)-[Android 14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_14). In my Java class there is a template like 4 choices but when I click any of them nothing happens and I didn't see any errors in [LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) (also when running).

I was using some clicklisteners and ProgressDialog for these buttons (it was showing a text like "searching for players..." and then redirecting when it found from the Firebase database), but I realised that progressDialog is deprecated.

Can it be the reason why it doesn’t response to clicks? If so, how can I change my code to ProgressBar (I guess it is the alternative) to fix this issue?

My code is like below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final Context context = this;
    FirebaseUser firebaseuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    uid = firebaseuser.getUid();
    user = firebaseuser.getDisplayName();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid);
    mDatabase_status = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid).child("status");
    kullanici = new database();
    kullanici.status(mDatabase, "off");
    postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                win = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("win").getValue());
                if(win == null) {
                    win = "0";
                }
                lose = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("lose").getValue());
                if(lose == null) {
                    lose = "0";
                }
                TextView userinfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kullanicibilgisi);
                String newstring = "Hoşgeldin " + user + "&lt;br&gt;Galibiyetler: " + win + "&lt;br&gt;" + "Yenilgiler: " + lose;
                userinfo.setText(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(newstring).toString()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to load post.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    postListener_status = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                String userstatus = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                if ("on".equals(userstatus)) {
                    dialog.hide();
                    mDatabase.removeEventListener(postListener);
                    mDatabase_status.removeEventListener(postListener_status);
                    Intent intocan = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ikinciekren.class);
                    startActivity(intocan);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to load post.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(postListener);
    kullanici.status(mDatabase, "info");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDatabase_status.addValueEventListener(postListener_status);
            kullanici.status(mDatabase, "waiting");
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setMessage("Looking for a player, please wait ...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(false);
            dialog.show();
            //Ardından Intent methodunu kullanarak nereden nereye gideceğini söylüyoruz.

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Answer (score -2):

The issue you're experiencing might not necessarily be related to the deprecated ProgressDialog, as it should still function properly even if deprecated. However, it's a good idea to migrate to the newer components for future compatibility and better performance.

To replace the `ProgressDialog` with a ProgressBar, you can make use of a ProgressBar widget directly in your layout XML file and control its visibility programmatically. Here's how you can do it:

1. First, in your layout XML file (`activity_main.xml`), add a ProgressBar:
2. In your Java code, replace the `ProgressDialog` with the `ProgressBar`:

   ```
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialize ProgressBar
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    // Rest of your code...
    // Remove the dialog initialization here since we're not using it anymore.

    btn = findViewById(R.id.button4);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDatabase_status.addValueEventListener(postListener_status);
            kullanici.status(mDatabase,"waiting");

            // Show ProgressBar
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Hide the ProgressBar when appropriate
            // dialog.hide(); // Remove this line since we're not using ProgressDialog anymore.
            // Add code to hide ProgressBar after desired task completion.
        }
    });
   ```

   }
3. Wherever you had dialog.show(), replace it with progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);, and wherever you had dialog.hide(), replace it with `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`.

By making these changes, you'll be using the modern ProgressBar widget instead of the deprecated ProgressDialog. Ensure that you handle the visibility of the ProgressBar appropriately based on when you want it to be displayed or hidden in your app flow.

Comment: You should have already seen this in the banner while posting your answer, but please note that use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you've validated this content. Also see the related [Help](/help/ai-policy) on this topic. We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable member of the community by contributing your own quality answers and questions in the future!